# Ajax returns json as array of objects. Starting from certain MAGIC number of objects it fails to output

Tags: ajax, json

I have ASP.NET page, it calls webservice via $.ajax and returns result in json format.

json data is a set of objects, every object is entity with own properties, for instance:

```
StorageEntity
{
 Capacity,
 Name,
 NameLink,
 RelatedEntityName,
 RelatedEntityNameLink,
 etc..
}
```

The problem is in some damned magic number:

when number of entities in result is 2622 - seems like NO MATTER how many properties contains StorageEntity - ajax response FAILS!

At first I thought that total amount of data is too big. So I reduced format of some verbose link properties. This way I reduced amount of result data by 20%. However, magic number has not changed!!

Just for information: stringify-ed result json's length was 5MB and after optimization is about 4MB.
I know it's anyway too much and will think on it.

But please, explain me - why it has not helped and still there are 2622 records that are not output (2621 is ok), no matter what is total amount of data arrived??

p.s. I have tried various stuff like maxJsonLength and especially MaxJsonDeserializerMembers - nothing helps...

Comment: can you check the integrity of that particular record to make sure there isn't something in the data which is bombing? Sounds awfully suspicious.

Comment: I have checked. It does not depend on data. But one more strange thing: when I indicate to output this mysterious amount: 2622 records and error happens in ajax - ajax webservice method itself is called twice or even more times! Instead of once, as when I call 2621 records or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out, that removing ANY property (not reducing their textual representation) was fixing the problem. But I don't want to lose any of my properties, so...

solution is maxItemsInObjectGraph parameter for data contract serializer.

You just need to add this

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                 <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="307200"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

into web config of your site.
My entity had a lot of properties and this number, multiplied by number of records, appeared to be greater than 64K set by default.